# How to rename columns with row character values using tidyverse pipeline?

Tags: r, dplyr, str-replace

input:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  a = c("z", "x", "y"),
  b = c("m", "n", "o"),
  c = c("p", "q", "r")
)
```

desired output: replace 2nd and 3rd column names with first row values (2nd and 3rd column).

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  a     m     p    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 z     m     p    
2 x     n     q    
3 y     o     r
```

This is what I tried so far. As you see I am using the vector `c("m", "p")` which is not what I want, I want it to be dynamic. I also tried `cur_data()` but it does not work :/.

```
df %>% 
  rename_with(
    ~ str_replace(., ., c("m", "p")), tail(names(.), 2)
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   rename_with(~  unlist(df[1, -1]),  names(.)[-1])
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  a     m     p    
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 z     m     p    
#2 x     n     q    
#3 y     o     r
```

---

Or use `rename`

```
df %>% 
       rename(!!! setNames(names(.)[-1], .[1, -1]))
```

---

Or could use `set_names`

```
df %>% 
     set_names(c(names(.)[1], unlist(.[1, -1])))
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know another path not using df inside rename_with?. In my real data, it is a large pipeline that I would not like to cut to create another df.

Comment: @AlvaroMorales i added an option with `rename`.  Hope it helps

Comment: It does help. Tks.

Comment: Do you know why the point `.` does not work in `rename_with(~  unlist(df[1, -1]),  names(.)[-1])` instead of `df`?

Comment: @AlvaroMorales It is because inside the `rename` the `.` is the column name and not the value of that column

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit adventurous, but still can be modified for more columns:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)


df %>%
  rename_with(~ df %>%
                select(b, c) %>%
                map_chr(., ~ first(.x)), .cols = c(2, 3))


# A tibble: 3 x 3
  a     m     p    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 z     m     p    
2 x     n     q    
3 y     o     r
```